# MAC OS - Running JavaScript (using Node.js) with AppleScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, google-chrome, applescript

In my MAC OS I have installed **Node.js** from the following link: http://nodejs.org/download/ (http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.29/node-v0.10.29.pkg).

This is because I need to run a JavaScript on Google Chrome. I am using the following code in AppleScript,

```
do shell script "supervisor \"/Applications/xyz.js\""
```

But get the following error:

> error "sh: supervisor: command not found" number 127

This works fine when run via Terminal like this:

> supervisor /Applications/xyz.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your path enviroment variable is setup differently so that inside Applescript it cannot find the application.

For example in applescript ....

`do shell script "echo $PATH"`

returns

`"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

But in terminal ...

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

So I'd just add the full path of the executable in applescript and that should fix the problem...

`do shell script "/path/to/app/supervisor ...."`

---

Here is an official explaination...

*The issue is that which application you tell determines the environment for the shell script — the working directory, environment variables, and so on. Most applications have the same environment, but relying on this is a maintenance risk. If your AppleScript is running in osascript, the working environment comes from the shell osascript was run from, which is completely separate from any other application.*

You can read more about it here

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html